# Retrieving single json object from python requests results as list

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to retrieve only requestId object from json results after querying my API.

my code:

```
def findRequests(group, token, user):
    headers = { 'accept': 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'token': token,
        'user': user}
    endpoint = 'requests/find'
    body = {'groupIDs': [group], "createdDate": {'operator': "BETWEEN", 'fromDate': "01-APR-2020 00:00:00", 'toDate': "21-APR-2020 00:00:00"}} 
    r = requests.post(url = host + endpoint, headers = headers, json=body, verify=False)
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    print (data[0]['requestId'])
```

json data:

```
[{'requestId': 2567887, 'requestName': 'Here is a sample name', 'requestSubject': 'sample subject', 'createdDate': '01-APR-2020 14:06:03'}, {'requestId': 7665432,...}]
```

then I would like to save all the values for requestId object found in results as a list:

```
 myRequestsList = print(findRequests(group, token, user))
```

However the above will only return a single requestId and not all of the ones that were returned in data variable in def findRequests(group, token, user). What am I doing wrong?

Output:

```
2567887
None
```

Desired output:

```
2567887,
7665432
```

Could someone help me with this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Your function should `return` not `print`

Comment: just changed to `return (data[0]['requestId'])` but when trying `myList = print(findRequests(group, token, user))` afterwards it still returns only a single Id and not all of the Ids found in json data. Is there something else Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should modify your func:

Then, assign the variable to the func, not the print:

```
myRequestsList = list(findRequests(group, token, user)))
```

**(!)** However, I assume that group,token, user are replaced by other variables.

And finally, to get the output:

```
for req in myRequestsList:
 print(req)
```

Later edit:

```
def findRequests(group, token, user):
    headers = { 'accept': 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'token': token,
        'user': user}
    endpoint = 'requests/find'
    body = {'groupIDs': [group], "createdDate": {'operator': "BETWEEN", 'fromDate': "01-APR-2020 00:00:00", 'toDate': "21-APR-2020 00:00:00"}} 
    r = requests.post(url = host + endpoint, headers = headers, json=body, verify=False)
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    final_list = []
    for each_req in data:
      final_list.append(each_req['requestId'])
    return final_list

myRequestsList = findRequests(group, token, user)

for each in myRequestsList:
 print(each)
```

Comment: I've tried the above and when running this bit  `myRequestsList = list(findRequests(group, token, user))` it says `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Any idea what am I doing wrong here? thanks!

Comment: It is because `findRequests(group, token, user))` retrieves a integer; do you mind sharing the json or just a small part of it (containing a12bd-fr145-52dg,
b67da-pl132-53dg,
c78aa-de111-890)

Comment: Hi andreis11, just added in my question as "json data". Would you be able to help with this?

Comment: That's why I asked :) let me have a look

Comment: @Baobab1988 check the later edit section of the answer

Comment: I've tried the updated answer but on this step `myRequestsList = findRequests(group, token, user)` it throws  `NameError: name 'each_req' is not defined`. Sorry for so many questions (maybe some of them are obvious), but how can I define each_req in the above? thanks in advance!

Comment: Np about the questions :) My bad, used  with` instead of `for`. modified the func. `for each_req in data:` instead of `with each_req in data`. Updated the answer. Sorry again.

Comment: It worked now! thanks a lot for helping me with this!

Comment: Hi @andreis11 would you be able to help me understanding how can I get two specific or more json objects from my data? For example:  'requestId' which you already shown me above but also 'requestName'? thank you!

Comment: Hi @Baobab1988 Included some samples in https://repl.it/repls/IdolizedEducatedDecompiler